# IF Function (less than a value but higher than another value)

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to make IF Function produce a value based on a cell that's higher than one value (A) but less than another value (B) eg

Assume B5=15

=if (10<*B5<20), "Good", "Bad")

Is this possible?

**Please ignore the * before B5, had to include it because for some reason, I could add the 'less than' sign without the texts vanishing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
=IF(AND(10<B5, B5<20), "Good", "Bad")
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Your response psyched me up and I tried to do create a formula for three possible outcomes; "Good", "Better", "Best".

My attempt was if(and(10<B5, B5<20), "Good", "Bad"), if(20<B5,"Best").

Needless to say, the system spat the code back to my face.

Comment: @EkanemEno. Try =if(20<B5,"Best", if(and(10<B5, B5<20), "Good", "Bad"))

Comment: can you use this with IFS?